# unable to add sip addresses with set-mailcontact cmd from csv

Tags: powershell

I want to create new mail contacts that are generated from other organization with the command:

```
get-aduser -properties *
```

I export it to csv and 
then I create contacts succesfully from csv but I cannot add skype address (sip) with the command

```
$contacts = Import-Csv "c:\contact.csv"
ForEach ($contact in $contacts){New-MailContact ...}

ForEach ($contact in $contacts){Set-Contact ...}

ForEach ($contact in $contacts){
    Set-Mailcontact $contact.EmailAddress -EmailAddresses @{Add="$contact.msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress"}
}
```

How can I add the parameter bulky "msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress" with the command `set-mailcontact`
not: I can set it one by one

Comment: Are you trying to add the attribute msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress to the contact with a value of `$contact.msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress`? Or are you trying to add the value of `$contact.msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress` as an email address alias to the contact?

Comment: I'm tring to add the value of $contact.msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress as an email address alias to the contact from the csv

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is accessing a property name with a `-` character. You can just surround the property name with single quotes (`''`) making it a literal string.

```
Set-Mailcontact $contact.EmailAddress -EmailAddresses @{Add=$contact.'msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress'}
```

Comment: yes, while you are writing this post I realized it. when I run the cmd it returns an error but it works.
thank you very much

Comment: It probably returns an error because the `msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress` property normally has a SIP address `sip:something@domain.com`. The `-EmailAddresses` parameter wants values that are `SMTP:`, `smtp:`, `X400:`, etc.